# Formatting column as time in r

Tags: r, dplyr, lubridate

So I think i am overcomplicating this, but I've tried a few functions in R using the lubridate package but none are returning what i need.

I will be joining two dataframes based on Time and they both have time columns formatted accordingly:

**DF1**

```
c("11:15 AM", "12:00 PM", "3:15 PM", "6:40 PM", "6:15 PM", "7:10 AM"
)
```

**DF2**

```
c("1:19 PM", "8:58 AM", "10:00 AM", "7:05 PM", "9:30 AM", "12:05 AM", 
"3:53 PM", "9:25 PM", "7:30 AM", "11:00 AM", "11:31 AM")
```

So I just need them to be consistent for a future merge, meaning they should be formatted as times, preferably using lubridate.

Comment: I recommend taking a look at `anytime()`, which has been really great for my similair usecases.

Comment: that didn't work, NA'd everything @mhovd

Comment: And can you verify they are both the same structure? Ex `class(df1)` . You Also may consider changing them to a different time structure before the merge. I feel the “AM/PM” would get muddy. Maybe convert to 24 hr time, and then Convert back. You may want the function `hms()` as it deals with hours minutes seconds from Lubridate package

Comment: @DanielJachetta can confirm, both are class = character. But your approach will totally work, i don't even need to change it back, 24 hour time will work.